# what is the meaning of pull back in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading the twilight's book in english but i am blocked. I don't understand the meaning of pull back in this sentence:

> "I kept my face pulled back into my hood as I walked to the sidewalk, crowded with teenagers."

I don't know if she means that she removes her Hood or she put her Hood on her head.
If anybody could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a weird way of saying that she kept her face hidden by the hood. She was already wearing the hood and she kept it on most likely to hide her face.